# how to use pandas.DataFrame.sum() to sum columns by column-indexnumber rather than index-string

Tags: python, sum

I have the following file where for each column name, there are several columns.
So, I cant refer to columns by string. I think I should use an indexnumber. However, I dont know how to do it.

[image]

I tried the following code to sum the "D" column ("Banana"):

```
column_list=[3]
x = file[column_list].sum(axis='rows')
x
```

But I get an error message stating:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: What is `KYHT_CSV_DF`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change it. It was the original name of the file. I have now changed it to "file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.iloc[:,3].sum()
```

should do the trick. But you would be much better off, keeping your dataframe consistent, i. e. avoid duplicate column names.